# Editing layout in Android

Tags: android, layout

I have two questions :

I am developing part of an Android App , in the main activity I added two text fields and one button and I am trying to call them by id as shown below :

```
Send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Send)   // Giving error in Send 
StudentName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);   // Giving error in edittext
```

and then I added `OnClickListener` to the button , as shown below :

```
Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                job = new MyJob();
                job.execute();
            }
        });
```

I added both Send (my button and the textfields) in the `R.java` but it is not accepting them because the modification was done manually . I added import `android.R`  , but it did not solve the problem .

My second question :

I am trying to edit my layout (graphically) but I do not know how to show it in eclipse  !!!

Please Help me and sorry if my questions are stupid .

Comment: take care of java naming conventions, variables should start with lowercase..

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.R
```

`android.R` are resources from the `Android` package. TYou need to `import your.package.R`

Answer (score 0):

For editing a layout in Eclipse open up the XML for the view/layout you are making. Then at the bottom of the code just above the tabs that say declaration, problems, javadoc there should be a tab that says Graphical Layout this will show your layout graphically.

Importing stuff by Id is done how blackbelt has said

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, delete the "Gen" (automatically generated files) package and then clean the project, the errors will go away.

Secondly, for layout design you can open the .xml files and switch to design tab for the GUI way to edit layouts. Hope that makes sense.